# While calling Post request via flutter DIO package It throws unhandled Exception Error

Tags: python, android, flutter, dart, post

I'm very new to the flutter, trying to send a POST request to the flask server consisting of image data using the flutter DIO package. I'm successfully able to call it through POSTMAN

sending post request  in flutter app with DIO package as below

```
   PickedFile? _image;

  //this is a code get image from Camera
  _imageFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile? image = await ImagePicker()
        .getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  //this is a code get image from Gallery
  _imageFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile? image = await ImagePicker()
        .getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }


Future<String> uploadImage(PickedFile file) async {
    print('calling');
    Dio dio = new Dio();

    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: fileName, contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg")),
    });
    var response = await dio.post("https://count-object.herokuapp.com/upload",
        data: formData);
    print(response.data['id']);
    return response.data['id'];
  }
```

I ran into error as below by sending a request as above fashion

```
flutter ( 1731): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]
E/flutter ( 1731): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819
E/flutter ( 1731): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678
E/flutter ( 1731): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1731): #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:1
E/flutter ( 1731): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1731):
E/flutter ( 1731): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:618
E/flutter ( 1731): #1      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1452:47)
E/flutter ( 1731): #2      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
E/flutter ( 1731): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:169:20)
E/flutter ( 1731): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:719:47)
E/flutter ( 1731): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:740:13)
E/flutter ( 1731): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:550:5)
E/flutter ( 1731): #7      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:61:12)
E/flutter ( 1731): #8      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:33:5)
E/flutter ( 1731): #9      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:466:45)
E/flutter ( 1731): #10     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1452:47)
E/flutter ( 1731): #11     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
E/flutter ( 1731): #12     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:169:20)
E/flutter ( 1731): #13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:719:47)
E/flutter ( 1731): #14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:740:13)
E/flutter ( 1731): #15     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:550:5)
E/flutter ( 1731): #16     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:606:7)
E/flutter ( 1731): #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter ( 1731): #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter ( 1731): #19     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter ( 1731): #20     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter ( 1731): #21     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 1731): #22     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter ( 1731):
```

at the server side terminal window throws this error

```
2021-06-23T12:14:34.147330+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.171.159 - - [23/Jun/2021:12:14:34 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 192 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8"
2021-06-23T12:14:40.603690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/upload" host=count-object.herokuapp.com request_id=76b0d4c5-76fc-4599-9801-10e8dc9259d8 fwd="157.50.34.16" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2880ms status=200 bytes=141699 protocol=https
```

!UPDATE
I tried  catching the error it caught below error

```
E/flutter (15704): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
E/flutter (15704): <title>400 Bad Request</title>
E/flutter (15704): <h1>Bad Request</h1>
E/flutter (15704): <p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
E/flutter (15704):
E/flutter (15704): #0      _MyHomePageState.uploadImage
package:count_objects/main.dart:196
E/flutter (15704): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15704):
```

How can I send POST requests successfully as in POSTMAN and retrieve the image back as response? any suggestion or guide on this will be helpful thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post parameter key is wrong.
In the postman screenshot, the post parameter is `image` where as in your code, it's `file`. Change the key to `image`.

Sample code:

```
 File file=File("file_path_here");
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    "image":
    await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename:"file_name.jpg"),
  });

  var response = await Dio().post("https://count-object.herokuapp.com/upload", data: formData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround your network calls in a try catch block

```
Future<String> uploadImage(PickedFile file) async {
    print('calling');
    Dio dio = new Dio();

    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: fileName, contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg")),
    });
    try{
         var response = await dio.post("https://count- 
             object.herokuapp.com/upload",
        data: formData);
        print(response.data['id']);
        return response.data['id'];


    } on DioError catch(e){
        throw Exception(e.response?.data); 

   }
  }
```

`throw Exception(e.response?.data);` this will give you a hint of what's going wrong

Comment: Done. Check out my edited question for catched error details. I couldn't make sense of it

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your request is ok, you might be missing the proper headers or body for a Bad Request response.

Comment: Yes that's the cause. I'm not familiar with sending request using DIO package. It works with postman